# Would it ever be correct to say "a technology"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

As in "a user's interaction with a technology"? - when technology means a technological device such as a phone, rather than the branch or application of technology.

Comment: Yes, why not? I might be missing something. EDIT: After your edit, no, probably not. You could say "a user's interaction with a device", or something similar.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify what I meant by technology. Would it still be applicable? @loading...

Comment: I edited my comment =) @Rosie

Comment: I don't think you can validly use the noun ***a technology*** to reference *a specific actual object* (a phone, for example). It's an *example / instantiation* of a (certain type of) technology. But I still can't get on with the current trend towards using ***a software*** to refer to a specific instance of "software technology* - what I would call a ***program*** (or perhaps *a **piece of** software*).

Comment: If not "a technology", do you think "a piece of technology" or "a technological device" sounds better?

Comment: i suspect it and others descriptive  of technology will enter the English lexicon over time.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. Dictionaries give example sentences; you may or may not find some that help you. //  With 'television was a new technology' (two Google hits), note that 'television' means 'the technology and industry of producing and broadcasting television programs' not 'the device in the front room'.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically, I would say no - it's too unclear and can be interpreted as the branch/application as well as the device.

I think referring to hardware as *a physical device* is much more clear.

> She knew how to interact with the physical device the minute she held it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe colloquial speech has accepted this---[Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/technology) seems to have embraced this definition of technology:

> n. A device, material, or sequence of mathematical coded electronic instructions created by a person's mind that is built, assembled, or produced and which is not part of the natural world.

Answer (score 0):

It should read "One's use of an electronic tool." A technologist would ascribe one's role as a user but they are devoted to categorizing people.

I am always pained by people and their devotion to what they term "Technology". What they refer to is today's current, usually electronic, fashions. Stonehenge is an active working technology so long as the sun and moon keep rising and setting. So are movable type and current means of peeling potatoes. The use of the word as a blanket term to specify the very very latest method of information manipulation (used to be COBOL, now XML and on we go) belies a profound ignorance in the fundamentals and an active disinterest in learning them.